# Extracting features from grain images, of different aspect ratio

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scaling, aspect-ratio

#### Context:

1. This image is taken from far away : [Eg1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuUjB.png)
2. This image is taken from closer : [Eg2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9scy.png)
3. This image is taken from really close : [Eg3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbFmO.png)

This is mainly because of the Threshold I have set, `if A < 300 or A > 1800: continue`

```
def Cluster(I):
    I_detected = np.copy(I)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(I_detected, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    num = 0
    grain_coord = []
    area = []
    perimeter = []
    for c in contours:        
        A = cv2.contourArea(c)
        if A < 300 or A > 1800: 
            continue
        print(num, A)
        num += 1

        minAreaRect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
        rectCnt = np.int64(cv2.boxPoints(minAreaRect))
        cv2.drawContours(I_detected, [rectCnt], 0, (0,0,0), 2)
        P = cv2.arcLength(c, closed=True)

        grain_coord.append(rectCnt)
        area.append(A)
        perimeter.append(P)

    return I_detected, num, np.array(grain_coord), area, perimeter
```

This Threshold is important as if I set the threshold to vary a lot then it will pick up the other grains too but then the features that I am trying to extract from the grains will also vary quite a bit. Like follows :

1. [Eg2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XqlG.png)
2. [Eg3.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G98tT.png)

These are the same images but with Threshold set to : `if A < 300 or A > 3500: continue`

And the results/features are as follows:

- [Result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z1TJ.png)
- [Result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQiBD.png)
- [Result3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQ3Al.png)

#### Issue:

Focus on the first 4 columns of each result.

Result1 & Result2 have deviation mainly in area and perimeter whereas the height and width dont differ much.

Result3 is completly different and has drastic differences in all 4 parameters.

#### Question:

Is there a way in which I dont have to worry about the distance from where the image is taken and still get minimum variation in the extracted features?

I am just looking for a way to resolve this or to get some alternate methods of approaching this.

Comment: You need to use size invariant features, such as area over squared perimeter. But the smaller the objects, the larger the uncertainty around the true value because of the pixelization. Subpixel evaluation of the area and perimeter might help.

Comment: I am taking 8 features into consideration, [ h, w, A, P, A/P, A/(A+P), A/(h*w), Diameter ].

`Subpixel evaluation of the area and perimeter might help`

could you eleborate or provide a link so i can go through.

Comment: Your features are not size independent.

Comment: yes exaclty so what all features do you recommend ?

Comment: Have a look at the Hu moment invariants.

Comment: So you are selecting object based on size, then find it doesn’t work if the object size varies? Did I get the issue right? You could estimate the distance at which the image was taken, then use that to scale objects. Maybe using the median object size as a reference?

Comment: yes thats kinda what i am looking for. `"You could estimate the distance at which the image was taken"` : How can I achieve it, any ideas ? @[cris-luengo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7328782/cris-luengo)

I will look into Hu Moment too. @[yves-daoust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1196549/yves-daoust)